# PFObjects not saving in database

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a item in the "Items" class and several images in the  "Images" class. After this i want to create a relation between the column pictures in "Items" and point to the images i just added. I've tried with following, but it does not add anything at all. Seems like the saveInBackgroundBlock is not being called?

```
@IBAction func addToServer(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    var imageCell: ImageViewCell = tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)) as ImageViewCell
    var adressCell: AdressViewCell = tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as AdressViewCell
    var contentCell: ContentViewCell = tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)) as ContentViewCell



    if imagePicked?.count > 0 && adressCell.adressField.text.length() > 0 && contentCell.priceField.text.length() > 0 && contentCell.contentField.text.length() > 0 && catBool == true {


        var address = adressCell.adressField.text + ", Denmark"



        var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in


            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {

                var price = contentCell.priceField.text.toInt()
                var categoryObject: PFObject = self.objectArray?.objectAtIndex(self.currentIndex!) as PFObject

                var itemObject:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Items")
                let coordinates = placemark.location.coordinate as CLLocationCoordinate2D
                let geoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude)
                itemObject.setObject(geoPoint, forKey: "location")
                itemObject.setObject(contentCell.contentField.text, forKey: "description")
                itemObject.setObject(price, forKey: "price")
                itemObject.setObject(categoryObject, forKey: "category")



                var relation:PFRelation = itemObject.relationForKey("pictures")


                for var i = 0; i < self.imagePicked?.count; i++ {

                var image:UIImage = self.imagePicked?.objectAtIndex(i) as UIImage

                    var imageObject = PFObject(className: "Images")

                    var imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
                    var theFile = PFFile(data: imageData)
                    imageObject.setObject(theFile, forKey: "image")



                    imageObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                        println("lol1")
                        if (success != nil) {
                            relation.addObject(imageObject)
                            itemObject.saveInBackground()

                        }
                    }

                }





            }

        })



    } else {
        println("Please fill in all informations")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and verify if it is called or not?

Comment: no but since println("lol1") is not being called i guessed that its not ?

Comment: well you should do some debugging and figure out if that line is called. The missing printed text indicates that the closure is not executed, so probably the save method is not called as well. Set breakpoints in the loop, if it never stops try with the outer one, etc. There can be several reasons  for your code not to work, so first try to narrow down until you find something for which you can say "it's this line of code". Without that, it's very hard to figure out what's wrong.